# how to autosave the multiple radio-button value of different class and name attribute in mysql database table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have multiple radio button with different name attribute and with different class names. I need to auto-update these value to the mysql database table.
I am able to auto-update the first value of radio button(i.e,"gender-type") and
when I click on second radio button(i.e,"skincolor") it's value is not updating into the database table.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4">

<h6 class="mb-2 pb-1 " style="font-size: 20px;">Gender: </h6>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="femaleGender"  />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="femaleGender">Female</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="maleGender" />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="maleGender">Male</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" id="otherGender" />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="otherGender">Other</label>
</div>

</div>


<div class="col-md-6 mb-4">

<h6 class="mb-2 pb-1 " style="font-size: 20px;">Skin Color: </h6>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="color1" id="color1"  />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="color1">color1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="color2" id="color2" />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="color2">color2</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="color3" id="color3" />
  <label class="form-check-label " for="color3">color3</label>
</div>

</div>
  <script>

function autosave()
{
  var gender = $("input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val();
  var s_color = $("input:radio[name='s_color']:checked").val();

  if(gender !=" "&& s_color !=" ") 
  {
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch1.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:
  {
    
    
  send_gender:gender,
  send_s_color:s_color,
  

    send_id:id
    },

    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data){
        if(data != ""){
                    $("#post_id").val(data);
        }

        $("#autosave").text("Data saved");
        } /* success */
}) /* ajax */
} /* filter */

}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you have only shown HTML & Javascript is it reasonable to assume that this question has nothing to do with PHP & mySQL and is more a Javascript problem than anything?

Comment: How is the `autosave` function invoked?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the code given how the Javascript/jQuery function `autosave` is actually invoked and nor is it clear whether or not this is an issue with the PHP so the following might or might not be of interest. There is no jQuery in this small fragment of Javascript - I don't use it so would do it a disservice but this is simple vanilla Javascript.

A small modification to the HTML ( not absolutely necessary but syntactically correct ) would be to use a `section` to define each of the radio groupings - which has the benefit of allowing us to easily count the number of radio groupings on the page and to compare that with the number of `checked` radio buttons - when these are the same the ajax function will be sent - thus ensuring that **all** radio buttons are included in the POST request which should mean the PHP can update the db OK.

```js
const d=document;

// 1 radio button from each of these MUST be checked before ajax request is sent
let oSections=d.querySelectorAll('section');


d.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='radio' ){
    // Find ALL checked radio buttons
    let col=d.querySelectorAll('section [type="radio"]:checked');
    
    if( col.length === oSections.length ){
      // 1 radio from EACH section is now checked, create
      // the FormData payload to send via AJAX to the server.
      let fd=new FormData();
      col.forEach(n=>fd.set(n.name,n.value));
      
      // Send the request
      fetch( 'fetch1.php', { method:'post',body:fd } )
        .then(r=>r.text())
        .then(data=>{
          d.querySelector('#post_id').value=data;
          d.querySelector('#autosave').textContent='Data saved';
        })
        .catch(alert)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
section{
  border:1px dotted grey;
  margin:0.25rem;
  padding:0.5rem
}
h6{
  margin:0 0 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="col-md-6 mb-4">
  <h6 class="mb-2 pb-1 " style="font-size: 20px;">Gender:</h6>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" />Other
    </label>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="col-md-6 mb-4">
  <h6 class="mb-2 pb-1 " style="font-size: 20px;">Skin Color:</h6>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="Green" />Green
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="Orange" />Orange
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="Purple" />Purple
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="Red" />Red
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="scolor" type="radio" name="s_color" value="Gold" />Gold
    </label>
  </div>
</section>
```